# How to resolve MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.6 Error

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I have created a module name "Module Example", but when I built it, it gave me the error below.

```
Error   2   The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module Example\\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module Example\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Kindly suggest to me, what I can do to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have Nuget installed locally? What version of MSBuild do you have installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed MSBuild 1.4.0.65

Comment: Do you have it installed in the project via a Nuget package, or did you install it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those error came if current MSBuild not found.

Check you MSBuild version, latest MSBuild from Nuget is 1.4.0.65, which is different from your settings.
Try change the settings in "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" into correct folder.

Comment: yes i have already installed MSBuild 1.4.0.65, but this error still come. Why

Comment: Open "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" and edit <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib> to this <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.65\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>

Comment: I was also tried MSBuild 1.4.0.65, but this error still came. I don't understand why it came?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

go to Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console

After Package Manager Console loads, type the following command

```
PM> Install-Package MSBuildTasks
```

restart your Project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but I wanted to add my .02 in case anyone else has this problem. Using "Install-Package MSBuildTasks" did nothing to help me solve this issue, however **"Open "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" and edit  to this $(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.65\tools\MS‌​Build.Community.Tasks.dll"** absolutely did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the error:

> Error   2   The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module
>   Example\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module
>   Example\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

in the first path between "Module Example" and "packages" you can see two backslash, so you can fix it just modifying the "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" file, removing the backslash before "packages"

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, installed latest NuGet package and edited my .csproj and fixed this line:

```
  <Import Project="packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.196\build\MSBuildTasks.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.196\build\MSBuildTasks.targets')" />
```

Then my project built without error.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was to install the latest MSBuildTasks with nuget and then open the .csproj file in Notepad++ and do a search and replace for all the occurrences of the old version of MSBuildtasks with the new. So I replaced:  "1.4.0.128" with "1.5.0.196".

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue
         Unload the specific project and reload it